# Effect of database change on Xtrareports

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I am using xtrareports with my c# project and i ran into a problem. When i change the structure of one of my database table, the reports that depended on it needed to be created again because the datasource did not automatically updated itself. is there a way of doing this so that the reports are updated with the new updated datasource without having to make reports again?

Comment: I think that you are talking about re-binding a report to a data source rather than creating a report from scratch.  Do you use the built-in SqlDataSource? If so, rebuilding the result schema of SqlDataSource in Report Designer can do the trick [see this screenshot](https://documentation.devexpress.com/HelpResource.ashx?help=CoreLibraries&document=img25075.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Solution could be the below:

1. [Create and configure datasets in your project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04y282hb.aspx)
2. [Bind a Report to a Data Source Schema](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/4797/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Providing-Data-to-Reports/Tutorials-and-Code-Examples/Bind-a-Report-to-a-Data-Source-Schema)

Now if you have any changes in database then update the DataSet which you added in project according the database table structure changes. It will help you easily fix the reports for the small changes e.g. column name change, column datatype

After that just open the reports in designer and again configure/modify report for the changes you made to the dataset.

Hope this way you reduce your efforts to recreate the reports from scratch..

Answer (score 0):

If you mean when you add/modify a column in a procedure that feeds your report, you can:

Right click your data source in the field list menu and hit "Rebuild Result Schema"